# Using NestWhileList to determine smallest prime value in series

Tags: function-construction, recursion

I have a function recursively defined as follows:

$a_{n+1}-1=(a_n-1)\times lpf(a_n)$, whe $lpf(x)$ is the least prime factor of $x$.

Now, given an initial value of $a_0$, I would like to find the smallest value of $a_n$ such that $a_n$ is prime.

Here is my attempt at a code, with $a_0=6$.

`NestWhileList[((#1 - 1)*FactorInteger[#1][[1, 1]] + 1) &, 6, ! PrimeQ]`

However, my code always simply returns the initial value of $a_0$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe this `Last@NestWhileList[((#1 - 1)*FactorInteger[#1][[1, 1]] + 1) &, 6, 
 Not[PrimeQ[#]] &]` ?

Comment: It seems that `Not[PrimeQ[#]] &` does the trick! Any idea why `! PrimeQ` doesn't, however?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!PrimeQ` is **not** a function. (Try, for example, `(!PrimeQ)[3]` )

You need to use

```
  !PrimeQ[#]& (* or Not[PrimeQ[#]]& as suggested by @b.gatessucks *)
```

or

```
  Composition[Not,PrimeQ]
```

Then

```
 NestWhileList[((#1 - 1)*FactorInteger[#1][[1, 1]] + 1) &, 6, 
 Composition[Not, PrimeQ]]
```

gives

```
{6, 11}
```

as expected.

To take another example:

```
 Select[Range[5], !EvenQ]
 (* {} *)
```

while

```
 Select[Range[5], Not[EvenQ[#]]&]
 (* { 1, 3,5 }*)
```

Comment: thank you! If I have a function as the above and would like to track how many iterations the function has taken so far, how would I implement the monitoring? I know about the `Monitor` function but am not sure how you would implement it here.

Comment: @vincent, thank you for the accept. About tracking the iterations, maybe `j = 1; Monitor[
 NestWhileList[(j++; ((#1 - 1)*FactorInteger[#1][[1, 1]] + 1)) &, yournumberhere, ! PrimeQ[#] &], j]`?

Comment: yes, that's good for me. thank you!